# Eclipse PDT IDE switch workspaces without app relaunch

Tags: eclipse, phped

Is it possible to switch workspaces in Eclipse without relaunching the application?

I want to group projects with their file transfer settings, and switch between them without having to reload the application. PHPed has similar behavior.

I don't know if workspaces is the correct term with Eclipse. My setup is to use a seperate workspace for each site I'm working on, so I can have different projects for different servers like development or production. Also I like breaking sites down into different projects to allow for easier global searching. And in PHPed the startup lags when there are a ton files in each project which I do not know if it's the case with eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach in Eclipse is to put everything in one workspace and to hide the projects you are not working with at any one time.

Note that in Eclipse, a project does not have to be nested within a workspace, and one project can be part of more than one workspace.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch workspace in Eclipse from **File ---> Switch Workspace** :

[image]

However this function will merely auto relaunch eclipse with the specified workspace already set, so it is like close eclipse and restart with the new workspace but a little bit quicker.

However you can use different **WorkingSet** instead of different **workspace** in Eclipse to avoid to relaunch Eclipse every time that you need to switch project . Take a look at [this](http://blog.alagad.com/2007/10/29/using-eclipse-working-sets-instead-of-workspaces/) great tutorial to understand better how to use Workingset in place of workspace in your situation.